# Issue java.util.zip.ZipError: zip END header not found when open JAR with JD-GUI

Tags: jar, zip, decompiler, jd-gui

I have a problem when, I try to open a *Jar File* with **JD-GUI Decompiler**, the error is the following.

[image]

This error don't let me decompile the jar.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I did the following.

1. Change the extension **jar file to RAR file** or another compressed format.
2. Uncompresed  the file.
3. Open some file class inside the folder mentioned above with JD-GUI
4. Finally in JD-GUI tool, choose the option **File -> Save all Resources**